# Download button for HTML5 Audio

Tags: audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording

How do I get the download button to show on HTML5 audio?
I have seen many articles explaining how to hide the download button. But in my case, I need to show the button.

Comment: Do you have control of the server from which the audio files are served?

Answer (score 0):

It's not intended for you to have control over the presentation of the controls of the built-in media player.

While browsers do provide some things you can manipulate via CSS, this isn't really the best way.

If you want to ensure that a download button is present, you need to implement it yourself.

```
<a href="/path/to/media/file.webm" download>Download</a>
```